# validate form and send data to php page using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to send form data to php page before that i wan to validate all required inputs. bellow is my jquery.

```
$('form#Wall_Post').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    type = $('.shareType').val();

    for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
        if (!formData[i].value && formData[i].name == 'message') {
            alert('Message could not be empty');
            return false;
        }
        if (type == 'photos') {
            var fileName = document.getElementById("image").value
            if (fileName == "") {
                alert("Browse to upload a valid File with png/jpg/gif extension");
                return false;
            } else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "PNG") {} else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "JPG") {} else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "JPEG") {} else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "GIF") {} else {
                alert("File with " + fileName.split(".")[1] + " is invalid. Upload a validfile with png/jpg/gif extensions");
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (type == 'videos') {
            if (!formData[i].value && formData[i].name == 'videoUrl') {
                alert('Video Url could not be empty');
                return false;
            }
            video = validateVideoUrl();
            if (video == false) {
                alert('Not a valid youtube/vimeo video URL');
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (type == 'location') {
            if (!formData[i].value && formData[i].name == 'location') {
                alert('Place could not be empty');
                return false;
            }
            if ((!formData[i].value && formData[i].name == 'lat') || (!formData[i].value && formData[i].name == 'lng')) {
                alert('Not a valid place');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    btn = $('#btn-share');
    btn.button('loading');

    // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser
    //var form = $(this);
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: $('form#Wall_Post').serialize(),
        success: function(mesg) // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.wallupdate').html(mesg);
                //alert(mesg);
            }
    });
});
```

its working fine before add the validation code. i don't understand where i am doing wrong. I am new to jquery.

Comment: where is `formData` defined?

Comment: WHERE is this funtion validateVideoUrl()